# Replace a value for the nth column in a csv file with sed /awk/any linux tool

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I want to replace the 28th column in a csv file from '2020-03-08' to '2020-03-08 00:00' .
I have tried : `gawk -i inplace  -F"," '{sub($28,"&00:00"); print}' $filename` .
This misfires because $28 is a date which might even be empty , so it replaces any value in the file not specific 28th column .

Also, 2020-03-08 can be present anywhere in the csv file , it can get replaced instead of the 28th column .
How can i resolve this ?

Eg of a line in csv file:

```
1057481434,e0e529d7-0942-44b1-b26d-794809edb113,2020-03-08 00:20:54+00,2020-03-07 13:50:28+00,fc7557d9-900b-4739-a678-79273dbbcaaf,android,indoor,stationary,100,1774,1774,105,336305e8-abfc-41b6-a07e-50c297c517bc,indoor,f,,,t,,,2020-03-07 13:50:27.539555+00,2020-03-07 13:50:27.539555+00,,31.6838,76.5255,1600,0,2020-03-08,0,,,0,0,0,,"31.6838125,76.52552",America/New_York,ASUS_X00TD,asus,asus,0.8.0,com.pepkit.ssg,83,e172ebc7-a301-4ed0-98a8-d1b852cc2235
```

Comment: As an aside, Awk out of the box doesn't know how to cope with double-quoted fields in CSV files. If you need to do more elaborate processing than this, maybe switch to a tool with a proper CSV parser, especially if you are completely new to Awk anyway.

Comment: cool wanted to avoid rewriting the csv using bash or java

Comment: @divyangshah : I would use a language where you already get a CSV parser included. Hence, I wouldn't do this in bash anyway. Java might work (have no experience with the CSV libraries for Java), but Perl or Ruby for instance work fine. Note that your approach of using awk is not reliable, if the input file is really a CSV in general sense, because a comma can also occur **inside** a field, and awk can't cope with it. Also, fields could contain line breaks, which you can't handle trivially in awk either.

Comment: i dont have the above two issues so its cool , on the other hand even csv parser till the extent of knoweldge i have , dont edit a csv at a particular position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking the string in `$28` and replacing it anywhere on the line. Try

```
{ $28 = $28 " 00:00" }1
```

or, if you insist on using `sub`,

```
{ sub(/$/, " 00:00", $28) }1
```

Notice how the third argument indicates *where* to replace, instead of on the entire input line.

If you only want to replace when `$28` is non-empty, make the action conditional.

```
$28 { $28 = $28 " 00:00" }1
```

The final `1` is a common shorthand for

```
{ print }
```

Recall that both the condition and the action are optional. If the condition is empty, the action is taken unconditionally. If the action is empty, the default action is to print the current input line. The lone `1` is a condition which is always true.

Comment: what is 1 at the end? and i tried both approaches its removing the "," why ?

Comment: It is shorthand for an unconditional `print`. This is a very common Awk idiom.

Comment: and i tried both approaches its removing the "," why ? getting something like this      1057481434 e0e529d7-0942-44b1-b26d-794809edb113 2020-03-08 00:20:54+00 2020-03-07 13:50:28+00 fc7557d9-900b-4739-a678-79273dbbcaaf android indoor stationary 100 1774 1774 105 336305e8-abfc-41b6-a07e-50c297c517bc indoor f   t   2020-03-07 13:50:27.539555+00 2020-03-07 13:50:27.539555+00  31.6838 76.5255 1600 0 2020-03-08 00:00 0   0 0 0  "31.6838125 76.52552" America/New_York ASUS_X00TD asus asus 0.8.0 com.pepkit.ssg 83 e172ebc7-a301-4ed0-98a8-d1b852cc2235

Comment: If you want to use comma as the output delimiter, add `BEGIN { OFS=FS }`. Again, this should be easy to find in any introduction to Awk.